# JavaScript - Creating a function to edit list items

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple To-Do app in HTML5. I have added a button to Add and Delete items.
However, I cannot figure out how to Edit items. Any idea how to create a function whereby I could edit items on this list?

```js
function get_todos() {
  var todos = new Array;
  var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  if (todos_str !== null) {
    todos = JSON.parse(todos_str);
  }
  return todos;
}

function add() {
  var task = document.getElementById('task').value;
  var todos = get_todos();
  todos.push(task);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));
  show();
  return false;
}

function remove() {
  var id = this.getAttribute('id');
  var todos = get_todos();
  todos.splice(id, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));
  show();
  return false;
}

function show() {
  var todos = get_todos();
  var html = '<ul class="list">';
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<li>' + todos[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i + '">Delete</button>  <button class="remove" id="' + i + '">Edit</button></li>';
  };
  html += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;
  var button_delete = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
  for (var i = 0; i < button_delete.length; i++) {
    button_delete[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
  };
}
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
show();
```

```html
<div id="content" style="">
  <!--Grid View Page-->
  <div class="panel" title="Title">
    <input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>
    <div id="todos"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create a function called `edit` - the rest should write itself, really

Comment: `I cannot figure out how to Edit items.` <- what exactly can't you figure out - be more specific and give us some example. if you have difficulties take a look here: [ask]

Comment: @Ovidiu Dolha - The splice() method adds/removes items from an array, and returns the removed item(s). What method do I use to Edit?

Comment: @Jaromanda X - i have created an edit function that isn't function and therefore did not decide to add it above as not to obfuscate the code.

Answer (score 0):

So right now your on click handler is just calling remove - even if the user clicks 'edit' -- so you would need to discern which button they hit, and call the appropriate function.

The reason that's happening right now is because when you write out the ID for the buttons - the edit buttons have the same class ('remove') - so they get triggered along with the delete buttons.

So the first thing to do would be to give the edit buttons their own class.  I would also give each list element it's own ID, so you can easily target them from your edit function.

```
    var html = '<ul class="list">';
    for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
        var list_element = "<li id=item'"+i+"'>";
        html += list_element + todos[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">Delete</button>  <button class="edit" id="edit' + i  + '">Edit</button></li>';
    };
    html += '</ul>';
```

Then, you will need to write another loop to target the edit buttons so that they call your edit function instead of the delete function.

something like this:

```
    var button_edit = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');

    for (var i=0; i < button_delete.length; i++) {
        button_edit[i].addEventListener('click', edit);
    };
```

You ALSO - might look into using JQuery [https://jquery.com/] - it makes selecting and responding to DOM objects easier more flexible than plain javascript.